# "Reaching "Back" for me"

Tags: word-meaning, lyrics

I was listening to the famous [**Bonnie Tyler**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonnie_Tyler)'s song [**"Holding out for a hero"**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bWcASV2sey0).

Then there is a line,

> Somewhere after midnight
> In my wildest fantasy
> Somewhere beyond my reach
> There's someone **reaching back for me.**

Does this mean, there is someone whose hand is so long or something that even though she is
beyond anyone's reach, someone reached to her? I'm nervous about the use of "back" here.

*Googling didn't help.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't overthink it.  It's just a lyric.

The general theme of the song is the Bonnie Tyler is waiting for a "hero" like the heroes in the movies etc.

And "the hero coming back to save the girl by reaching and taking her hand and pulling her forward out of danger at great personal risk" is a movie scene.  So she is fantasising about being rescued from peril by the hero who comes back to save her.

Like I said, don't overthink it.